# How to upload file on another domain?

Tags: codeigniter, upload

I have an external hosting server.

On that server I have 2 domains:

- `www.dom1.com`
- `www.dom2.com`

On `www.dom1.com` I have my whole web page (in Codeigniter). One of the functionalities is upload (users can upload their files.)

On `www.dom2.com` there is only one folder called upload_dom2. `www.dom2.com` is otherwise empty and not visible anywhere on the Internet. I would like to use it exclusively for upload. I imagine that this is a much safer way than letting the users upload their files on `www.dom1.com` where all my other files are (by the way, let me know if I'm wrong, please).

So, how do I do that? How do I upload a file - that user has uploaded in the framework of Codeignitors system (webpage) on `www.dom1.com` - in a folder called upload-dom2 on `www.dom2.com`

I know how to upload a file in a folder called uplod_dom1 that is located on `www.dom1.com`. This is a code that I use.

```
$pathd=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$config['upload_path'] = $pathd.'/upload_dom1';
```

But as said, that is not what I want. I want to upload to `www.dom2.com` (in its uplod-dom2 folder).

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Codeigniter FTP class. You can do this with any external website/server that supports FTP: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/ftp.html

Example code:

```
$this->load->library('ftp');

$config['hostname'] = 'ftp.example.com';
$config['username'] = 'your-username';
$config['password'] = 'your-password';
$config['debug'] = TRUE;

$this->ftp->connect($config);

$this->ftp->upload('/local/path/to/myfile.html', '/public_html/myfile.html', 'ascii', 0775);

$this->ftp->close();
```