# Using CodeIgniter file upload class with Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to use CI's file upload class with Google Cloud Storage?

the issue I'm facing is that you have to define an upload path in the file upload config, but it's not working when I set this as such:

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'gs://<bucket-name>/';
```

I think its because GCS needs a file name, but CI doesn't let you have a file name in the upload path.

So what can I do?

Should I move to conventional PHP uploads? Or is there a way around this?

Comment: You can use the upload library to upload the file locally.  This will give you all your information about the file, including the file name/type etc.  Then you would stream it to google cloud through their API.

Comment: App Engine doesn't allow you to write to the file system. So it has to be uploaded directly to GCS

Comment: I see, you can still upload the file into the buffer right? move_uploaded_file($FILES['name']['tmp_name'], "gs://<bucket_name>") ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload

Comment: I am having issues with that implementation, as when I try to add the require and use lines, it doesnt work. See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769342/unable-to-include-cloud-storage-tools-library-in-app-engine Trying to access the createUploadUrl throws a fatal error

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot upload to an external server using CodeIgniter's File Upload Class.  [The documentation is pretty clear that `upload_path` is meant to be a "folder" on the server where your CI is installed](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).

Comment: See [CodeIgniter's FTP Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/ftp.html) instead:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632722/how-to-upload-file-on-another-domain

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the config option (`upload_path`) you are setting, there is no such option on the createUploadUrl function [1]. It should be the folowing:

```
$config['gs_bucket_name'] = 'my_bucket'
```

no need to specify a GCS URI (gs://), just your bucket name

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload#createuploadurl_options

Comment: The config variable I posted is from CodeIgniter.

Comment: Got it @MrPablo . I'm afraid that what you want to do is not allowed, please read the blue highlighted ["Important"](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload) note.