# Unable to include Cloud Storage Tools library in App Engine

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

In my CodeIgniter project, I am unable to include the Cloud Storage Tools PHP library, as used in lots of example PHP code.

I have put the following at the top of an Controller extension, but I get an error when trying to use "CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl()"

```
require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;
```

This is the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CloudStorageTools' not found

Is this library automatically in the App Engine?

I thought this library was automatically there (seeing as there is an automatic Google Cloud Storage wrapper so you can use gs:// for uploading) but it seems like this isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the "require_once" statement as all SDK classes are auto-loaded: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Automatic_class_loading

Comment: I finally got it working. Yes you're right, the require_once isn't needed (not mentioned in the php docs!) But the problem was the "use" namespace. It won't work in my custom extension controller, it has to be in the controller that is using the CloudStorageTools

Comment: Hi @MrPablo , I am stuck into it. please help me. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I am stuck into this also. CloudStorageTools not found even in my Google deployed app @MKB

Comment: Hi @javipedrera, I was able to resolve the issue. I included the path `include_once APPPATH . '/vendor/autoload.php';` at the top of the created helper file where I wrote the functions to communicate with the library.